# "Constructor call must be the first statement in a constructor"

Tags: java, eclipse

So I've made a method named "voegUrenToe" which adds a number to the "uren" variable, however when I try to make another method which is supposed to call this method in particular it provides me with the following error code.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8nML.png)

!! isn't a duplicate, other posts didn't answer my problem.

Comment: Please show code here with your question, not in a link, and not in an image. The same for your error message.

Comment: please show your code in the question and not as an image. that makes it easier to read

Comment: this is a duplicate the fact that you do not understand the answer does not make this not a duplicate

Comment: If MY question is not answered then how is my problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

In your class "Tijdstip" you have a non-static void method voegUrenToe() where you try to call constructor. After you initialize your object, it makes no sense to call constructor again. If you want to change the value of your instance, you should do it by directly changing it like "uren = 1;"(rather than calling constructor again).

Answer (score 0):

The error is referring to the following part of your code:

```
public void voegUrenToe(){
   this(1);
}
```

`this()` can only be used to call a constructor from within another *convenience* constructor. In this case, it must be the first statement in the convenience constructor. For example, this is correct:

```
public Tijdstip(Tijdstip a){
   this(a.seconden);

   //other operations
}
```

You can not call `this()` from a method because, at that point, the instance has already been constructed.